# Structure with another structure into it

Tags: c, structure

How can I correctly access the ***price*** member from the ***category*** structure?

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SMAX 128

typedef struct {
  int price;
  char favCharacter[SMAX], edition[SMAX];
} category;

typedef struct {
  char title[SMAX], fname[SMAX], lname[SMAX];
  category *cat;
} book;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  book *data = malloc(100 * sizeof(book));
  (data->cat)->price = 10; //1
  printf("\n\n(*(data->cat)).price is: %d%s", (data->cat)->price, "\n\n");

  return 0;

}
```

My first attempt failed (//1)
What is the right way to solve this? *(I mean to have a structure with another structure)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating memory for `book`, but not for the `cat`s inside the books. Here's an example:

```
/* allocate a hundred books */
book *data = malloc(100 * sizeof *data);
/* allocate one cat per book */
for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    data[i].cat = malloc(sizeof *data[i].cat);

/* now you can use it */
for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    data[i].cat->price = 50;
```

Note: you need to add checks to make sure `malloc` doesn't fail before continuing using the returned memory. Also, it's best to avoid magic numbers such as `100` above. Furthermore, don't forget to `free` the memory later.

Comment: Just one question: If I declare a book variable like this: **book data;**, I will need to alocate memory for **cat** pointer?

Comment: Yes. `cat` is a pointer, which points to ... well ... until you assign something to it, somewhere completely random. So no matter how you get your `book`s, the `cat`s are still pointers that need to be initialized to point to _something_.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating an array of books in your line:

```
book *data = malloc(100 * sizeof(book));
```

So you should access an array element before accessing its contents:

```
data[0].cat->price = 10; // lets access element 0 for example.
```

But, first, you must also alloc data for the `cat` variable inside each array element:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    data[i].cat = malloc(sizeof(category));
}
```

Now you can access your elements correctly.

Don't forget to free the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
book *data = malloc(100 * sizeof(book));
(data->cat)->price = 10; //1
printf("\n\n(*(data->cat)).price is: %d%s", (data->cat)->price, "\n\n");
```

to

```
// 1. need explicit conversion
book *data = (book *) malloc(100 * sizeof(book));

// 2. allocate category for book *data
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) 
    data[i].cat = (category *) malloc(sizeof(category));

// 3. setting
(data[0].cat)->price = 10;

// 4. read
printf("\n\n(*(data->cat)).price is: %d%s", (data[0].cat)->price, "\n\n");
```